# How to populate data dynamically by selecting options in select box using jsp servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, servlet-3.0

I have a select box in JSP page.

```
<select  name="name" id="name">
    <option  value="0" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">select a batch</option>
    <option    value="1">one</option>
    <option  value="2">two</option>
</select>

this is my servlet code 
  String admissionnum2= request.getParameter("name");  
    try
{
   con = DBConnection.createConnection(); //establishing connection
statement = con.createStatement(); 
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from studentsdata where class = '"+admissionnum2.toString()+"'");  
while(resultSet.next()) 
{
    str+="<tr><td>"+resultSet.getString("name")+"</td></tr>";
       String num = resultSet.getString("admissionnum");
         String standard=resultSet.getString("class");
       request.setAttribute("name",str);
request.setAttribute("admissionnum",num );
}
RequestDispatcher rd=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Data should be populated from the database based on the selected option in the select box. I am using servlets for database connection. When I am selecting an option, data is retrieved according to the option from the database. But the problem is by default select box is displaying first option value. How to solve this? Can anybody suggest me?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. You want to select an option and see the data where?

Comment: I have divided the webpage into two frames.In one frame i have a select box.Based on the select box value list of data should be populated into second frame of webpage.I have retrieved data from the database.And its populating correctly according to the options selected in the select box.But the problem is after submiting the option its displaying first option value

Comment: Basically you have to implement the `onChange` jQuery method. Retrieve data according to the option selected. Use a `model.addAttribute("data", data);` (in the case of Spring at least). And then read that data with jstl. You could show us the code maybe

Comment: this is my servlet code